# is safe-thread or syncronized the property "Status" from IAsyncAction interface in order to know if a thread was finish it?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to know if is syncronized the property "Status" from IAsyncAction class interface, because I want to use it to detect from another thread(main one) if that task/thread was completed or keep running yet

Comment: You'd only be interested in the Completed or Error or Canceled status.  At which point the async operation is finished so there is never a synchronization issue, it cannot change anymore.

Comment: Thanks Hans for your comment

Answer (score 0):

I could confirm, yes, is synchronized the property Status,
I had doubt about how this is handled, so I decided to use the debugger of Visual Studio and make experiments this property
So, First I had to confirm the value was assigned to other variable with the value 2 (Canceled)

But using Disassembly feature, I followed each assembler instruction until find when use the "get" function of property variable

So I found the instruction where have the current state and how is passed to next variable

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrUqs.png)

As we can see the register edx contain the value 2 (Canceled) but this is handle by the instruction
lock cmpxchg ...

According with this link:
http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_41.html

.. allow the instruction to be executed atomically...
In other words this allow execute the interchange of data without another thread interference with that execution

Thanks to all , I Hope this help